# Core Data not working in my Controller. How to link managedObjectContext to my Controller?

Tags: iphone, core-data

im first time using core data concept to simply insert and retrive some info..

i have `userInfoAppDelegate.h` , `userInfoAppDelegate.m`  and `DisplayController.h` , `DisplayController.m`.

now i have succesfully addded and retrived data in my delegate files, here is code

userInfoAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeController.h"

@class RootViewController;

@interface UserInfoAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{    
    HomeController *hController;
    UIWindow *Window;        
}    
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RootViewController *rootViewController;        
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;    
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;    
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

userInfoAppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{         
   //some code...

UserInfo *newUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserInfo"
             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];    

if (newUser != nil){             
    newUser.firstName = @"test"; 
    newUser.lastName = @"test";
    newUser.userName=@"b@test.com";
    // newUser.bDate = [NSDate date] ;
    newUser.department=@"Admin";

    NSError *savingError = nil;        
    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError])
    { 
        NSLog(@"Successfully saved the context."); 
    } 
    else
    { 
        NSLog(@"Failed to save the context. Error = %@", savingError);
    } 
}     

else {        
    NSLog(@"Failed to create the new person.");
}   

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];    

/* Here is the entity whose contents we want to read */ 

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserInfo"
       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];    

/* Tell the request that we want to read the contents of the Person entity */
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity]; 
NSError *requestError = nil;    

/* And execute the fetch request on the context */ 
NSArray *users = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                    error:&requestError];

NSLog(@"%@",users);       
if ([users count] > 0){
    NSUInteger counter = 1; 

    for (UserInfo *thisUser in users){            
        NSLog(@"Person %lu First Name = %@", (unsigned long)counter, thisUser.firstName);
        NSLog(@"Person %lu Last Name = %@", (unsigned long)counter,
              thisUser.lastName);
        NSLog(@"Person %lu Department = %@", (unsigned long)counter,
              thisUser.department ); counter++;
    }
}

else { 
    NSLog(@"Could not find any Person entities in the context.");
}

  //some code...

}
```

// ABOVE CODE WORKED WELL WITH PROPER RESULT , BUT SAME CODE NOT WORKING WITH MY `DisplayController.h` AND `DisplayController.m`.

Comment: let me know if DisplayController code needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get AppDelegate reference in your controller and then where you are using `self.managedObjectContext`, use `delegate.managedObjectContext`

Here's a small sample

```
userInfoAppDelegate *delegate = (userInfoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserInfo"
       inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: do i need to import UserInfoAppDelegate.h to my controller or it is accessible from all controllers?

Comment: you need to import it where you want to use it

Comment: worked! though something wrong.
can any explain what this means?

`NSError *savingError = nil;     
        
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError])
        { 
            NSLog(@"Successfully saved the context."); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            NSLog(@"Failed to save the context. Error = %@", savingError);
        }`

Comment: if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError])
add "!" :)

Comment: i have successfully inserted and retrieve data but can i see where those data are stored? my Data model file is UserInfo.xcdatamodeld.

Comment: go to document directory of you simulator there you will find sqlite file

Comment: Great! ..one another issue..as i am accepting user info in first screen and inserting them into database and then retiring it and displaying in another screen. so what i guess is time taken to insert and fetch data is larger thn sweeping screen so i get old result on displaying!, can i hold the screen for some time so tht insertion and retrieval is finished?

Comment: yeah u'r right...even i cant know weather app is sleeping or crashed for some time! :( ...then wht should i do?